# SQL find number of columns

Tags: sql, mysql

[image: Database schema]

Ok, I have this logical scheme about movies, actors, directors, etc. in an SQL database, and I want to create a query that returns me all movies with more than 2 copies.

I've been trying, but I cant get it right, can anybody help me?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you have been trying.

Comment: nothing that could be executed so i though it was pointless

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right query is something like this:

```
SELECT m.title, COUNT(*)
FROM movies m JOIN
     copies c 
     ON m.mid = c.mid 
GROUP BY m.title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

If you don't need the title, then the `JOIN` is not even necessary:

```
SELECT c.mid, COUNT(*)
FROM copies c 
GROUP BY c.mid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```